# CakePHP complex find from three tables dependent

Tags: sql, cakephp, find

I have three tables:

```
Stories (id, category_id, sub_category_id, name, story),

Categories (id, parent_id, lft. rght, name), 

SubCategories (id, name)
```

They are properly related and all is working fine. But now I need to find stories which belongs to specified category and/or sub_category, by name autocompleate dialog. Example: user entered "dog bone" and must search for such a name in categories/subcategories and after find all stories whitch belongs to found categories. No problem when doing many finds, but in SQL I can make one query. Can this be done in CakePHP in one find ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please provide the sql query.. sometimes i found easier to create the find if i see the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few options for doing this, some of them below

a) linkable behavior - https://github.com/Terr/linkable/wiki

b) bindModel - http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations

c) adhoc-joins http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find

read up on them and see what suites your needs best.

Comment: Mmm.. I think linkable behaviour is what I need. Only no documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

either you solve it with the table assocations or you use "containable" behavior.

"Containable" Behavior is very easy to use and easy to implement.

[Containable Behavior in Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)

Comment: I am using Containable behaviour, but there are no possibilities to get parent (Category) results depending on child (Product) conditions. Or I am wrong?

Comment: maybe it will help when you check this site about assocations http://book.cakephp.org/view/1046/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

Comment: also you should reconsider you structure of categories / subcatgories. or maybe i understand that "subcategories" wrong

Comment: Categories/Subcategories is just for example. In real life I have 5-6 tables where I am searching information and then show results. I am migrating old plain SQL to CakePHP ORM.

Comment: There is possibility to limit main result by contain model condition. If I do `$this->Dealer->find('all', array('contain' => $contains))` and in `$contains` is `array('Category' => array('conditions' => array('active'=> true)))` can show just all dealers where category (and there will be more models contained with conditions) is true?